# How do you output Fat Free PHP variable as HTML?

Tags: php, html, fat-free-framework

I am trying to output a variable from F3 which contains HTML.

```
$message = "<p>Hello, <b>World</b></p>"
```

I am outputting it as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    {{ @message }}
</div>
```

The problem is it displays exactly like so:

```
"<p>Hello, <b>World</b></p>"
```

Instead of just:

Hello, **World**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per their docs:

```
<div class="container">
    {{ @message | raw }}
</div>
```

[Source](http://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates#data-sanitation)

Comment: nevermind , it was a non f3 related issue, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to disable the [automatic HTML escaping](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#ESCAPE).

```
$f3 = Base::instance();
$f3->set('ESCAPE', false);
```

The rendered template will look like the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Hello, <b>World</b></p>
</div>
```

Now it's necessary to escape untrusted data with the `esc` macro. Example:

```
{{ @message | esc }}
```

See also:

- [Views and Templates](http://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates#DataSanitation)
- [Template Directives](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#TemplateDirectives)